# Postgres How to speed up select statement on partitioned table

Tags: database, postgresql, select, postgresql-performance

I'm looking for ways that I can reduce the time to run select statements in my data warehouse.

We are currently running Postgres Enterprise 9.3.4.10 with the intention of upgrading to 9.6 within the new few months.

There is a Fact table with about 95 million rows with b-tree indexes on all of the foreign key / id columns.  The foreign key columns are a mix of smallint / integer data types.  They are all single column indexes. There are also some measures such as dollar amounts that we use for aggregation (sum / avg).  These fields are NOT indexed.  The table is updated on a daily basis using JDBD insert/update statements via Pentaho.  The table is also partitioned by activity_date_key.

Running "select sum(amount) from table where date between 20160701 and 20160801" runs in 0.2 seconds but if I increase that timeframe to be between 20160101 and 20160801 the run time jumps up to 70 seconds.  (The date field is of type integer).

I'm looking for some ideas on what I can do to reduce this time.  Possibly different types of indexes?  I read that 9.6 comes with BRIN indexes (block range indexes) but not sure if that will help me.  Are there any database config parameters that I can safely tweak?  Maybe my problem is just too much data in general?  Any tips are welcome.  And let me know if you needed any more info on my environment.  Thank You.

Ryan

Comment: Edit your question, and include the information from [the postgresql-performance tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: Unrelated, but: `BRIN` indexes where introduced in 9.5, not in 9.6

Comment: If there isn't an index on "table"."date", there probably should be.

Comment: I'll edit my original post with all of the additional info.  Thanks for replying everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some additional info on my setup and some answers to questions so far:

Yes there is an index on activity_date_key. There are 16 b-tree indexes in total which represent the foreign keys.

I do want to consider BRIN indexes as we are going to upgrade to 9.6. Is there any reasoning to believe that it would be useful in conjunction with a partitioned table (by date key) which is already b-tree indexed on the same key?

Hardware Configuration 2CPUs with 16 cores each vendor_id : AuthenticAMD , cpu family : 21, model : 2, model name : AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6378, cpu MHz : 2400

192GB of RAM SAS Disks on a netapp storage array

There are 18 other database on this server - very overloaded.

Explain (analyze, buffers) output for select count(*) from fact_gc_activity where activity_date_key bewteen 20160101 and 20160801:

"Aggregate (cost=372804.89..372804.90 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=121284.418..121284.418 rows=1 loops=1)" " Buffers: shared hit=72295 read=47564" " -> Append (cost=0.00..347567.97 rows=10094768 width=0) (actual time=350.581..118020.641 rows=10023451 loops=1)" " Buffers: shared hit=72295 read=47564" " -> Seq Scan on fact_gc_activity (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)" " Filter: ((activity_date_key >= 20160101) AND (activity_date_key <= 20160801))" " -> Index Only Scan using fact_gc_activity_201601_activity_date_key_idx on fact_gc_activity_201601 (cost=0.43..54563.87 rows=1748572 width=0) (actual time=350.577..5734.825 rows=1748572 loops=1)" " Index Cond: ((activity_date_key >= 20160101) AND (activity_date_key <= 20160801))" " Heap Fetches: 0" " Buffers: shared hit=2 read=4880" " -> Index Only Scan using fact_gc_activity_201602_activity_date_key_idx on fact_gc_activity_201602 (cost=0.43..41641.89 rows=1331873 width=0) (actual time=183.811..3071.842 rows=1331873 loops=1)" " Index Cond: ((activity_date_key >= 20160101) AND (activity_date_key <= 20160801))" " Heap Fetches: 0" " Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3737" " -> Index Only Scan using fact_gc_activity_201603_activity_date_key_idx on fact_gc_activity_201603 (cost=0.43..45535.79 rows=1456368 width=0) (actual time=171.306..3069.430 rows=1456368 loops=1)" " Index Cond: ((activity_date_key >= 20160101) AND (activity_date_key <= 20160801))" " Heap Fetches: 0" " Buffers: shared hit=2 read=4086" " -> Index Only Scan using fact_gc_activity_201604_activity_date_key_idx on fact_gc_activity_201604 (cost=0.43..34124.85 rows=1088621 width=0) (actual time=179.636..4707.148 rows=1088621 loops=1)" " Index Cond: ((activity_date_key >= 20160101) AND (activity_date_key <= 20160801))" " Heap Fetches: 0" " Buffers: shared hit=2 read=3076" " -> Seq Scan on fact_gc_activity_201605 (cost=0.00..43008.71 rows=1116181 width=0) (actual time=157.550..13863.706 rows=1094721 loops=1)" " Filter: ((activity_date_key >= 20160101) AND (activity_date_key <= 20160801))" " Buffers: shared hit=5374 read=20892" " -> Index Only Scan using fact_gc_activity_201608_activity_date_key_idx on fact_gc_activity_201608 (cost=0.43..1281.07 rows=37832 width=0) (actual time=0.058..19.571 rows=34741 loops=1)" " Index Cond: ((activity_date_key >= 20160101) AND (activity_date_key <= 20160801))" " Heap Fetches: 0" " Buffers: shared hit=124" " -> Seq Scan on fact_gc_activity_201607 (cost=0.00..64043.08 rows=1670672 width=0) (actual time=0.029..765.421 rows=1653358 loops=1)" " Filter: ((activity_date_key >= 20160101) AND (activity_date_key <= 20160801))" " Buffers: shared hit=38983" " -> Seq Scan on fact_gc_activity_201606 (cost=0.00..63368.72 rows=1644648 width=0) (actual time=0.030..81989.732 rows=1615197 loops=1)" " Filter: ((activity_date_key >= 20160101) AND (activity_date_key <= 20160801))" " Buffers: shared hit=27806 read=10893" "Total runtime: 121284.642 ms"

Configuration Settings: - shared_buffers: 4GB - effective_cache_size: 2049MB - work_mem: 10MB - default_statistics_target: 100

Comment: Don't add additional information as answers. Edit your question, but make sure you preserve the formatting of the execution plan.

Answer (score -2):

Try tuning your postgresql, in "postgresql.conf" you will find a lot of parameters which will speed up your postgresql, for query you have "work_mem" but be careful with the number of connections you have, [pgtune](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/) will give you an idea how to set parameters, or read this [article](http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql-performance.html) for a clear vision.

Comment: Changing the server configuration isn't the best first step. Even if this *were* the right way to change the server configuration.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake i meant "data/postgresqin.conf"

Comment: Now you've made *two* mistakes.